# Laravel: get last Insert id from query builder

Tags: laravel-5

I am new in laravel and trying to get last inserted id from this query:

```
DB::select("INSERT INTO current_survey (`name`, `created_by`, `description`)  SELECT `name`, `created_by`, `description` FROM survey WHERE id=survey_id");
```

this query working well, can any one suggest me how this is possible in laravel?

Thanks

Comment: $id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

Comment: hey, thanks  it works..post your answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try it once :-

```
$id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 10):

According to laravel document

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts

If the table has an auto-incrementing id, use the insertGetId method to insert a record and then retrieve the ID:

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
);
```

Comment: This will help in avoiding an extra line

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = DB::statement("INSERT INTO current_survey (`name`, `created_by`, `description`)  SELECT `name`, `created_by`, `description` FROM survey WHERE id=survey_id");

//your inserted id
$last_id = $query->id;
```

Comment: I tried `$query->id` and got the following error: `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object ` with `insert()` method :/

Answer (score 0):

If you **primary field** column name is `id` then simply use

```
$lastInsertId = DB::table('tablename')->insertGetId($data);
```

When using **PostgreSQL** the `insertGetId` method expects the auto-incrementing column to be named `id`. If you would like to retrieve the ID from a different **"sequence"** for example `product_id`, you may pass the column name as the second parameter to the `insertGetId` method.

```
$lastInsertId = DB::table('tablename')->insertGetId($data, 'product_id');
```

laravel documentation : [insertGetId](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insertGetId)