# laravel 8 - Get inserted data id via query builder

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-8

Here is the way I save my data

```
$data = array();

$data['date'] = $request->date;
$data['user_id'] = $request->user_id;
           
$save = DB::table('appointments')->insert($data);

if($save) {
    foreach($request->time as $time) {
        $data = array();

        $data['appointment_id'] = $save->id;
        $data['time'] = $time;

        DB::table('times')->insert($data);
    }
            
    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'Appoitment time created success',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );
}
```

But for another table join with `appointments` table

When I try to save data with way in this line `$data['appointment_id'] = $save->id;` I get and error

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

How can I get `appointments` insert success id?

PS

```
$id = DB::table('appointments')->orderBy('id','desc')->first();
```

I don't want to get last insert data-id with this way may be its can be wrong if multiple user try to save

Comment: [`insertGetId`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#auto-incrementing-ids)

Comment: thank you its work can you add this as answer so I can mark as paa

Comment: $id = DB::table('appointments')->insertGetId($data);  add this as answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: get last Insert id from query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000204/laravel-get-last-insert-id-from-query-builder)

Comment: It's not different enough from the linked question to need its own answer. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61025278/9381601) in particular is exactly what the documentation I pointed to describes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `insertGetId` to get the `id` of the created record:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#auto-incrementing-ids

`$id = DB::table('appointments')->insertGetId($data);`

--

***Note***

> **If the table has an auto-incrementing id**, use the insertGetId method to insert a record and then retrieve the ID